# Error trying to install xxtea with pip

Tags: python, windows, pip

I need to install xxtea to use in python. I tried with pip and got a vsvarsall.bat error. So I read a load of SO posts and installed VS 2010 C++ express, windows SDK 7.1, have added an environment var called INCLUDE with C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include

If i just run `pip install xxtea -U` it gives `ValueError: ['path', 'include']` error
if go to windows SDK 7.1 command prompt and run `pip install xxtea -U`

I get

`error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

with a load of undeclared identifier errors above

I have python 3.4.1 64bit on windows 7 64bit

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Use the SDK command prompt, which sets up the build environment via the SDK's `Bin\SetEnv.cmd` script. Then the problem is the definition of [`unhexlify`](https://github.com/ifduyue/xxtea/blob/v0.1.4/xxtea.c#L159). The declarations on line 165 (`int i, j, top, bot;`) need to be moved to the first line of the function definition.

Comment: That done it. Many thanks